# Bootstrap-datepicker getDate wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/).  I do a `getDate` immediately after doing a `setDate`, but get the wrong value. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.6.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<input class='date' data-date-format="M d, yyyy">

<script>
     var new_date = moment().subtract('days', 30).toDate();
     console.log('new_date:', new_date);
     $('.date').datepicker('setDate', new_date);
     $('.date').datepicker('update');
     console.log('date:', $('.date').datepicker('getDate'));
</script>
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't like your `,` in the date format. Drop it and it prints the correct date. Note that datepicker also uses `,` as a multi-date separator.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I'd like to keep the comma if possible though, just because I think it looks better that way.

Comment: Maybe if you change the default multi-date separator you can use the comma in formatting.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  Thanks.  You should submit this as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it doesn't like your `,` in the date format. Drop it and it prints the correct date. Note that datepicker also uses `,` as a multi-date separator.

Changing the default `multidateSeparator` allows the comma in the formatting string.

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    multidateSeparator: ";"
});
```

or

```
<input class="date" data-date-format="M d, yyyy"
                    data-date-multidate-separator=";" />
```